# Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 Upgrade Failure

Tags: upgrade

I recently tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04. When I ran the upgrade, it ran into a problem upgrading one of the modules, and wouldn't let me continue. However, when it stopped, it doesn't appear to have reverted all of the changes. Now my computer believes it is 14.04, but it actually isn't/isn't fully upgraded, and I can't figure out how to try to run the upgrade again.

Any ideas?

Comment: What error? How you know that your system reports 14.04? Why you think that isn't upgraded?

Comment: The art on the screen shown on startup shows 14.04, but nothing else had changed, it seemed. It seems to have worked now, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade your machine by opening a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and entering the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will attempt to upgrade all the packages that weren't upgraded previously.

When you run `sudo apt-get upgrade` again and if it tells 
`0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0  not upgraded`, then you can be sure that your system is up-to date.

Comment: Alright: I ran that, but I'm still not sure if it's completely updated. It did something (for sure), but I don't know what. Is there any way to tell if it's completely updated?

Comment: After the system is updated, just run `sudo apt-get upgrade` again. If it tells `0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0  not upgraded.` then you can be sure that you system is up-to date. I have edited the answer above.